# bash script changing changing date and time stamp

Tags: bash, date, time, touch

I'm trying to write a bash script that asks for data/time and a file name and then changes the last modified date of the input file:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
#set -x
echo "Please enter the new date/time stamp"
echo -n "in the form of [ YYYY MM DD hh mm ss ] [ENTER]:"
read YYYY MM DD hh mm ss

echo -n "Please enter the file name. [ENTER]:"
read FNAME
echo touch -d \"$YYYY"-"$MM"-"$DD" "$hh":"$mm":"$ss\" \"$FNAME\"

touch -d \"$YYYY"-"$MM"-"$DD" "$hh":"$mm":"$ss\" \"$FNAME\"
```

I am getting an error which is confusing:

touch: invalid date format ‘"2016-01-21 03:03:03"’

if I copy and paste the line I echoed to screen, from the script :

```
touch -d "2016-01-21 03:03:03" "test.docx"
```

the script works perfectly.

As always, any insights would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any quote magic in your script, just call `touch` as:

```
touch -d "$YYYY-$MM-$DD $hh:$mm:$ss" "$FNAME"
```

Comment: From `man touch`:  -d, --date=STRING parse STRING and use it instead of current time